# Display messages between two users. Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I need to display messages between two users. I've created table `conversations`, it has `con_id`, `user_id`, `friend_id` fields. I don't know how to write logic so that messages will be shown only those who are written between these two users which is in `user_id` and `friend_id` fields.

Storing message:

```
public function store(Request $request, $id)
{
    $conv = new Conversation();
    $conv->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $friend = User::where('id', $id)->first();
    $conv->friend_id = $friend->id;
    $conv->message = $request->input('message');
    $conv->save();
}
```

Comment: You need to user `where` clause here using `Auth::id` method. Check here. https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/security

Comment: Basic but the idea is just this but buffed up:`if ($sent_to == $current_user_id) { }` you'd check the query results against the current user id.

Comment: @Francisunoxx I know. But I don't know how exactly.

Comment: @feknuolis can you post your Controller where this logic happens.

Comment: @Francisunoxx I've posted `store` method

Comment: Can you also add the View for this.

Comment: I don't have written any logic because everytime it fails. So I don't have any view. I need a sentence which only would show messages between two users.

Answer (score 2):

Get messages where Auth-user is sender (user_id) and receiver is the friend_id, and vice versa. Order by time (assuming you have column created_at).

```
$sent_by_me = DB::table('conversations')
->select('message', 'user_id as sender_user_id', 'friend_id as receiver_user_id')
->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
->where('friend_id', $friend_id);

// messages sent to me by friend
$conversation = DB::table('conversations')
->select('message', 'user_id as sender_user_id' 'friend_id as receiver_user_id')
->where('user_id', $friend_id)
->where('friend_id', Auth::user()->id)
->union($sent_by_me)
->orderBy('created_at', 'asc')
->get(); 

return View::make('show.conversation')
     ->with('conversation', $conversation);
```

In blade you're the receiver if sender_user_id differs from Auth::user()->id, otherwise you're the sender. Using one-line-if to determine the css style for message. 
Note: you must check that user really is logged in before you can use Auth::user()->id, otherwise it will fail if user is not logged in. Using middlewares in this case will do it.

```
@forelse($conversation as $msg)
    <div id="message_{{ $msg->id }}" class="{{ $msg->sender_user_id === Auth::user()->id ? 'sent_message' : 'received_message' }}"> {{ $msg->message }} </div>
@empty
    No messages!
@endforelse
```